# Rails: Find records with a certain combination of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `User` model that has many `Events`. Each `event` has two attributes, `name` and `device`.

I want to fetch all `users` that have at least one event with:

```
events.name = 'Logged in' AND events.device = 'iPhone'
```

and at least one event with:

```
events.name = 'Upgraded' AND events.device = 'Desktop'
```

I'm looping through a hash of conditions, so I also need to be able to do the OR statement with an ActiveRecord scope like so:

```
results = User.all
results = results.where("events.name = 'Logged in' AND events.device = 'iPhone'")
results = results.where("events.name = 'Upgraded' AND events.device = 'Desktop'")
```

The query above doesn't work because it looks only for events that match all the conditions.

How do I write this query in ActiveRecord in Rails 4?

Comment: Make it this and try: `User.joins(:events).where("(events.name = 'Logged in' AND events.device = 'iPhone') OR (events.name = 'Upgraded' AND events.device = 'Desktop')")`

Comment: Thanks, reading your comment I realised that I didn't specify one key requirement, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code

```
User.joins(:events).where("events.name = 'Logged in' AND events.device = 'iPhone'").where("events.name = 'Upgraded' AND events.device = 'Desktop'")
```

you are chaining the calls and filtering the first set `where("events.name = 'Logged in' AND events.device = 'iPhone'")` further with another condition `.where("events.name = 'Upgraded' AND events.device = 'Desktop'")`.

**EDIT:**

```
User.joins(:events).where(" (events.name = 'Logged in' AND events.device= 'iPhone') AND (events.name = 'Upgraded' AND events.device = 'Desktop')").
```

In the Rails 5, there will the addition of `OR` clause (loot at Github issue discussion).

Comment: Thanks, reading your comment I realised that I didn't specify one key requirement, I've updated my question. So I guess there's no way to do a scoped OR statement in Rails 4?

Comment: In Rails 4 there is not an ActiveRecord implementation of OR clause, you have to write it "raw" SQL.

Comment: I will edit my answer regarding the edit of your original question.